# Cannot run program in java inside a package in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, package

why my vscode is not runing programs in package.
i am able to run them once I import package and run the program outside any package.
But when I am trying to run them inside a package it is giving an error-:

Error: Could not find or load main class arraystring
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

for example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP76H.png)

Comment: You working directory should be the root directory of your project.  In this case, programs.  You can click on open directory and select the programs directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.java` file has package `programs.progprac` and as you discovered that will lead to `javac` placing the `.class` file into `./programs/progprac/helloworld.class`. The class file also will have the package name inside, for reasons beyond this answer.

Now you tried "executing" that file by changing into the package directory and specifing it's name. But, the `java` command does not want the filename of your class (unlike for example the `python` command).

The syntax of the `java` (here from Java 17 documentation) command is different:

> To launch a class file:
>
> `java [options] mainclass [args ...]`
>
> -- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/java.html#synopsis

it wants the `mainclass`, which here is the "fully qualified class name", which is package + class name, `programs.progprag.helloworld` in your case.

If you specify that, java will look for that class in `./programs/progprag/helloworld.class` and it should work as you expect.

But if you run Java in the folder with the classfile and you give `helloworld`, it will look for `./helloworld.class` (and find it) but will see the package name inside is not empty. thus java rejects loading the file, finally failing with `helloworld` class not being found, because the class' file could not be loaded.

---

More recent Java versions (like Java 17) also have an option to execute "single source" files:

> To launch a single source-file program:
>
> `java [options] source-file [args ...]`
>
> -- ibd

Thus it looks to be possible to run the **`.java`** (not the `.class`!) using

`java helloworld.java`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be related to your workspace. Vscode running file takes the current workspace as the root directory.

I think you should release the directory structure when you show the problem. I have a simple reproduction here:

There is a package com.cn in the workspace and a app.java in the package.

[image]

[image]

This is consistent with what you showed, but the results are different. I think the directory structure is inconsistent, or there is an error in the location of the terminal when you run the file.